# How to unit test Lombok @SneakyThrows annotation existence under method

Tags: java, unit-testing, lombok

```
   @Test
    void annotatedClass() throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Class<? extends service> aClass = underTest.getClass();
        Method method = aClass.getDeclaredMethod("create", param.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        SneakyThrows sneakyThrows = method.getAnnotation(SneakyThrows.class);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(sneakyThrows);
    }
```

But assert is Null and private method annotated with @SneakyThrows

IDEA talk:
Annotation 'SneakyThrows.class' is not retained for reflective access

Can we beat annotation retention and be able to test it somehow?

Comment: Lombok replaces the annotations with actual code. The annotations are removed during compilation, which you can't beat AFAIK. However, you could test if the annotation would actually trigger by calling the method with parameters that cause the exception

Comment: What do you want to achieve? There might be other ways.

Comment: I want to test sneakythrows existence under private method, like I described below.

Comment: Unit test the behavior, not the presence of the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Lombok's `@SneakyThrows` has retention `SOURCE`, so it's not preserved in the compiled code. See the sources:

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface SneakyThrows {
    /** @return The exception type(s) you want to sneakily throw onward. */
    Class<? extends Throwable>[] value() default java.lang.Throwable.class;
    
    //The fully qualified name is used for java.lang.Throwable in the parameter only. This works around a bug in javac:
    //   presence of an annotation processor throws off the type resolver for some reason.
}
```

Here is a simple way to check whether `@SneakyThrows` is present over a method:

```java
class MyTest {

    @Test
    void testSneakyThrows() throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Class<IOException> exceptionType = IOException.class;

        assertThrows(exceptionType, this::myMethod);
        assertFalse(Arrays.asList(getClass().getMethod("myMethod").getExceptionTypes()).contains(exceptionType));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public void myMethod() {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because of retention I cannot test sneakythrows annotation existence. But I want to test It anyway somehow.

Comment: You should test the behavior: verify whether method throws unchecked exception and doesn't declare that exception in it's signature. You can use `Method.getExceptionTypes()` and `assertThrows` to implement described check.

Comment: @HolyDrug I've updated my answer, try the example.